# How can I do match after second level unwind in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am working on a software that uses MongoDB as a database. I have a collection like this (this is just one document)

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aef51e0af42ea1b70d0c4dc"),    
    "EndpointId" : "89799bcc-e86f-4c8a-b340-8b5ed53caf83",    
    "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:04.574Z"),
    "Url" : "test",
    "Tags" : [ 
        {
            "Uid" : "E2:02:00:18:DA:40",
            "Type" : 1,
            "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:04.574Z"),
            "Sensors" : [ 
                {
                    "Type" : 1,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-98")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 2,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-65")
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Uid" : "12:3B:6A:1A:B7:F9",
            "Type" : 1,
            "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:04.574Z"),
            "Sensors" : [ 
                {
                    "Type" : 1,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-95")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 2,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("-59")
                }, 
                {
                    "Type" : 3,
                    "Value" : NumberDecimal("12.939770381907275")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and I want to run this query on it.

```js
db.myCollection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$Tags" },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "Tags.DateTime": {
            $gte: ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:02Z"),
            $lte: ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:09Z"),
          },
        },
        { "Tags.Uid": { $in: ["C1:3D:CA:D4:45:11"] } },
      ],
    },
  },
  { $unwind: "$Tags.Sensors" },
  { $match: { "$Tags.Sensors.Type": { $in: [1, 2] } } },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      EndpointId: "$EndpointId",
      TagId: "$Tags.Uid",
      Url: "$Url",
      TagType: "$Tags.Type",
      Date: "$Tags.DateTime",
      SensorType: "$Tags.Sensors.Type",
      Value: "$Tags.Sensors.Value",
    },
  },
])
```

the problem is, the second match (that checks `$Tags.Sensors.Type`) doesn't work and doesn't affect the result of the query.

How can I solve that?

If this is not the right way, what is the right way to run these conditions?

Comment: Remove the leading `$` sign, so only `"Tags.Sensors.Type" : { "$in" : [1,2] }`

Comment: @dnickless oh my... yes it seems it was one of the problems. Thank you. I removed that. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: What does not work? Your sample data's `Tags.Uid` values do not match the one used in the filter if that's confusing you...

Comment: @dnickless Thank you for your answer. As I mentioned, this is just one document of the collection. The problem is when I use second `$match` the result always shows 0 but I have some documents that are match with this condition.

Comment: Try removing stages and individual filters one by one starting from the end of the aggregation pipeline to detect the offending bits. Using your sample data with the `Tags.Uid` value from your query I could get results back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$match` stage accepts field names without a leading `$` sign. You've done that correctly in your first `$match` stage but in the second one you write `$Tags.Sensors.Type`. Simply removing the leading `$` sign should make your query work.

Mind you, the whole thing can be a bit simplified (and some beautification doesn't hurt, either):

1. You don't need to use `$and` in your example since it's assumed by default if you specify more than one criterion in a filter.
2. The `$in` that you use for the `Tags.Sensors.Type` filter can be a simple `:` kind of equality operator unless you have more than one element in the list of acceptable values.
3. In the `$project` stage, instead of (kind of) duplicating identical field names you can use the `<field>: 1` syntax unless the order of the fields matters.

So the final query would be something like this.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
{
    "$unwind" : "$Tags"
},
{
    "$match" : {
        "Tags.DateTime" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:02Z"), "$lte" : ISODate("2018-05-06T19:05:09Z") },
        "Tags.Uid" : { "$in" : ["C1:3D:CA:D4:45:11"] }
    }
}, {
    "$unwind" : "$Tags.Sensors"
}, { 
    "$match" : {
        "Tags.Sensors.Type" : { "$in" : [1,2] } 
    }
},
{
    "$project" : { 
        "_id" : 0,
        "EndpointId" : 1, 
        "TagId" : "$Tags.Uid",
        "Url" : 1,
        "TagType" : "$Tags.Type", 
        "Date" : "$Tags.DateTime", 
        "SensorType" : "$Tags.Sensors.Type", 
        "Value" : "$Tags.Sensors.Value" 
    }
}])
```